# Why am I receiving this Error- "a resultset was expected but not genersated from query....."

Tags: sql, hive, case, hiveql

I am running a hive query that collects stats on two tables based on if there are instances of a given value within a field. However when I run the code below I receive an error:

```
 WITH AB AS (
    SELECT substr(A1.tm, 1,10) as MY_DATE , A1.MY_ID
    FROM db1.table1 A1 ,db1.table2 A2  WHERE
 A1.MY_ID=A2.MY_ID AND A2.TXT LIKE '%Check%' and LENGTH(trim(a2.txt))  < 65
    and  substr(A1.tm, 1,10)= date_sub(current_timestamp(),1)
    ),
    BC AS ( 
    SELECT  AB.MY_DATE,  AB.MY_ID ,
    CASE WHEN (TXT like '%Do you need assistance%') THEN '1' ,
    WHEN  (TXT like '%transfer%') THEN '2' ELSE NULL END 
    AS NODE
    FROM AB left JOIN db1.table2 BC ON AB.MY_ID =BC.MY_ID
    where substr(tm, 1,10)= date_sub(current_timestamp(),1)
    )
    CD AS (
    SELECT  AB.RPT_DATE, 
    SUM ( CASE WHEN NODE_1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) AS
    CONTAINMENT ,
    SUM ( CASE WHEN NODE_1=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) AS HANDOFF , 
    COUNT(DISTINCT AB.MY_ID) AS VOL_TOTAL
    FROM BC
    GROUP BY AB.RPT_DATE
    )
    SELECT coalesce(BC.RPT_date ,date_sub(current_timestamp(),1)) as MY_DATE  ,
    COALESCE(BC.VOL_TOTAL,0) AS VOL_TOTAL  ,COALESCE (BC.CONTAINMENT,0) AS CONTAINMENT ,
    COALESCE (BC.HANDOFF,0) AS HANDOFF ,
    'v' as catg
    FROM CD;
```

I receive the error of **"a resultset was expected but not genersated from query "With AB AS().....".** Any ideas or suggestion as why this may be?

I know there is not much background but is there anything missing in terms of syntax?

Comment: Time clash, modern cte's, but ancient comma separated joins...

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: So do you know where the error is within the code?

Comment: Can you run AB stand-alone? Do you get a result-set?

Comment: There are issues in your query: 1. comma after BC CTE. 2. In the select you are addressing BC columns but in the from is is a CD.  The query is not valid one. Please fix it before posting here, this is work you should be able to do

Comment: It seems to miss a comma before "CD AS"